# How to register only specific Interface/Impl pairs in Castle Windsor?

Tags: castle-windsor, registration

I have this hierarchy:

```
IRepository
    |
    |_____IRepository<T>_______________________________________________
              |                                                        |
              |_____Repository<TModelContainer, TEntity>               |
                        |                                              |
                        |_____SpecificRepository<TEntity>          IEntityRepository
                                  |                                    |
                                  |__________EntityRepository__________|
```

And I would like to have **only** the following registration pairs:

```
IRepository<T> / Repository<T>
IEntityRepository / EntityRepository
```

Based on http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx, I cannot understand how to achieve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.WithServiceDefaultInterface()` should do the trick

Comment: Would it be possible to register IRepository<TEntity> / EntityRepository by convention ?

Comment: ok now I have a real question :) I want to have all three registrations: IRepository<T> / Repository<T>, IEntityRepository / EntityRepository and IRepository<TEntity> / EntityRepository. But it doesn't seem to work... When I register first with default interface , and then with service base, or vice-versa, only the first registration is done.

Comment: if none of the out of the box options work for you you can always go `WithServiceSelect(s=>s.Name.Contains("Repository"))` or similar

Comment: Now it's all registered. But the issue is when I am asking IRepository<TEntity> I can have both implementation Repository<TEntity> or EntityRepository. I would like to give priority to the most derived type, EntityRepository.